# How to use Adobe Analytics with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, adobe-analytics, eas

I am looking for a method to integrate an Expo project with the Adobe Analytics. The existing resources usually recommend ejecting the project first and then using the Adobe's react-native libraries.

Is there any method to integrate without ejecting?
And if there is not, considering the EAS build also ejects a project, is there a method that we can use (like integrating the Adobe Analytics -somehow- at last minute during the eas build process)?